# Unity has CreateChildContainer, is there equivalent in SimpleInjector or LightInject

Tags: inversion-of-control, simple-injector, light-inject

We're in the process of evaluating SimpleInjector and LightInject to replace our current Unity implementation in our application. Unity has a method that allows a hierarchy of containers with a call to CreateChildContainer(). Is there an equivalent for SimpleInjector and LightInject?

Comment: Simple Injector has the LifetimeScope lifestyle for this. Can you give some specific examples of what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Where can I get a list of restrictions for both of these frameworks? i.e. list of what these frameworks don't yet do compared to Unity.

Comment: You can take a look at [this feature comparison](http://featuretests.apphb.com/DependencyInjection.html), which is based on [this blog](http://blog.ashmind.com/2008/08/19/comparing-net-di-ioc-frameworks-part-1/).

Answer (score 3):

[LightInject](http://www.lightinject.net/) uses the **PerScopeLifetime** and the **PerRequestLifetime** for this.

**PerScopeLifetime** creates just one instance of a given service per scope and disposes the service instance at the end of the scope if it implements IDisposable.

**PerRequestLifetime** creates new instances for each request (GetInstance) and disposes all instances at the end of the request.

The scope itself is started using the **BeginScope** method.

**PerScopeLifetime**

```cs
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(new PerScopeLifetime());
using(container.BeginScope())
{
    var firstInstance = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    var secondInstance = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    Assert.AreSame(firstInstance, secondInstance);
} //<- Instances implementing IDisposable are disposed here.
```

**PerRequestLifetime**

```cs
container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(new PerRequestLifetime());
using(container.BeginScope())
{
    var firstInstance = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    var secondInstance = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    Assert.AreNotSame(firstInstance, secondInstance);
} //<- Instances implementing IDisposable are disposed here.
```

Normally the **BeginScope** method is something that is called by the various extensions available to **LightInject**.

Examples of this can be found in [LightInject.Web](http://www.lightinject.net/#web), [LightInject.Mvc](http://www.lightinject.net/#mvc) and [LightInject.WebApi](http://www.lightinject.net/#webapi).

Comment: That 's pretty much how it works in Simple Injector, except that they are called WebRequestLifestyle and LifetimeScopeLifestyle.

Comment: Steven, I looked the comparison sheet at http://featuretests.apphb.com/DependencyInjection.html. Can you tell me if any of the info on that page concerning SimpleInjector are wrong? It seems that LightInject has a higher score. I'm wondering now if the page is out-dated.

Comment: @Ray: The comparison is still accurate. The Simple Injector score is quite low because of two reasons. 1. Some features are supported but didn't fit the generic test suite (that's when you see 'note'). And 2. Many features are deliberately left out, because we feel it steers developers into the wrong direction (such as auto-registering Lazy<T> and Func<T>), while those features could be implemented rather easily if required. (Side note: don't forget to use the @ sign in front of the name if you ask a question to make sure that person gets notified. I accidentally stumbled upon your question.)